# How to add external packages and run in rust compiler?

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I am compiling and building an example program using rust. I chose `rustc` instead of `cargo` for compiling because it being a simple personal test project. So far using `rustc` for compiling and building executable worked fine but when I tried to add an external `rand` package its giving me this error

```
1 | extern crate rand;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

This is the full code

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    for x in 1..11 {
        let random_number = rand::thread_rng()
            .gen_range(1, 101);
        println!("{} -> {}", x, random_number)
    }
}
```

How can I add external packages and run with `rustc`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible without Cargo, but you'll have to do what it normally does for you.

1. Download all the dependencies.
2. Compile all the dependencies with `rustc` using the correct flags.

```
rand v0.7.3
├── getrandom v0.1.14
│   ├── cfg-if v0.1.10
│   └── libc v0.2.66
├── libc v0.2.66 (*)
├── rand_chacha v0.2.1
│   ├── c2-chacha v0.2.3
│   │   └── ppv-lite86 v0.2.6
│   └── rand_core v0.5.1
│       └── getrandom v0.1.14 (*)
└── rand_core v0.5.1 (*)
```

`rand` isn't too bad, with only 8 transitive dependencies (including `rand` itself, not including duplicates). Still, you'll have to go to crates.io or github and download the correct version of the source for each.

Then comes compiling. The minimum you'll have to do to compile your own binary is `rustc -L dependency=/path/to/dependency/dir src/main.rs`. But remember that you have to do this for each of the 8 dependencies, and all of those have their own external dependencies. You'll also need to figure out the right order to compile them.

Moveover, some crates have their own settings in their `Cargo.toml` that have to be respected. Some crates even have a build script that needs to be compiled and run (`libc` is an example in this dependency tree).

---

Alternatively, you could just put

```
[dependencies]
rand = "0.7.3"
```

in your `Cargo.toml` and run `cargo build`. Your choice. Cargo is one of the nicest things about Rust, so I suggest you use it.

---

P.S. To see what exactly `cargo` is doing, run `cargo clean` to remove any already compiled dependencies. Then run `cargo build --verbose` (or `cargo build -vv` if you're brave). You'll see all the flags that get passed to `rustc`, scripts that get run and everything else.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to expand on @SCappella's answer. I would encourage you to use `cargo` as well. If you are familiar with package managers from other languages such as JS, PHP, or Python, you might be interested in [cargo edit](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-edit).

It allows you to run commands `cargo add rand` (latest version), `cargo add rand@0.7.3` (specific version), `cargo upgrade rand` (upgrade only `rand`), `cargo upgrade` (upgrade all dependencies) in CLI instead of editing `Cargo.toml` file directly.

To install it, run `cargo install cargo-edit`, and then read the [documentation on the website](https://github.com/killercup/cargo-edit/blob/master/README.md#available-subcommands) on how you can use it.