# How can you check compile errors of file with dependencies that is no direct cargo target?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to check whether a module would compile within the context of a cargo project (i.e. all the dependencies as well as the rust edition from Cargo.toml loaded). As far as I understand, with `cargo check`, this would only work for specified targets. Thus I could only check the compilation of the file if it were part of a target that I could build.

However, the project requires a bit of effort to set up and get running (especially since it is in an earlier development stage it doesn't really work) and currently I only want to check a single source file without a main function.

Using `rustc --edition 2021 --crate-type lib path/to/file.rs` only works for the basics but obviously doesn't load or link other crates (which I need).

I only found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59915954/how-to-add-external-packages-and-run-in-rust-compiler) that explains how to manually add dependencies to `rustc`, which obviously isn't my preferred approach. Is there a way to check if this file would compile with all the necessary crates linked against it with cargo?